# How to read Java Object model in jsp using ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to use iterate list of object model returned in my jsp using AJAX. Is there   Ajax framework  which I can use there. Below are psudeo code or steps:

1: From JSP make a ajax call to  Spring MVC Controller.
2: Controller will create and return one list of model object . ListuserDetailList.

3: This  userDetailList will be received inside my Ajax  call in jsp.

Now how can  I iterate this userDetailList in jsp page to create  table.

Model has three properties let say: UserName  UserLocation  Email are the fields . I dont want to use JSON format here.

Comment: why not to use json format here??? if you just want to iterate through object, you can return json from controller using @responsebody and then iterate as you like it on frontend

Comment: Because  for some architectural issues that is not recommended to use . Otherwise I have already done  similar thing  by using json

Comment: You can try requesting a jsp in iframe and using the value from there. The reason is that java will compile only jsp files and spring will populate model  data in view only when compiling occurs. So...